# Batch to show me files with *_????*.* in two folders

Tags: windows, batch-file

Sorry, but my English is very poor!
I have two folders with several files like below:

```
D:\Folder1\
START_0101.dat..
START_0105.dat..
START_0109.dat..
..
..
..
START_0250.dat.

D:\Folder2\
rms_20141124_0100.mdb..
rms_20141124_0108.mdb..
rms_20141124_0109.mdb..
..
..
..
rms_20141124_0250.mdb.
```

I need a batch script to show that files *109.mdb and *250.mdb exists in Folder2.
If exists, then display a message.

WINDOWS 2000

---

I can have several files in folder1, with this pattern "*_????.dat".
D:\Folder1\
START_0101.dat..
START_0105.dat..
START_0109.dat..
..
..
..
*_????.dat

I can have several files in folder2, with this pattern "*_????.mdb".
D:\Folder2\
rms_20141124_0100.mdb..
rms_20141124_0108.mdb..
rms_20141124_0109.mdb..
..
..
..
*_????.mdb

I need something like this:

if exist "d:\folder1*_????.*" set "found=1" 
if exist "d:\folder2*_????.*" set "found=2"

if "%1%" EQU "%2%" (
  echo file %found% exist
 ) else (
    echo file doesn't exist
 )

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So what have you written so far that isn't working for you?

Comment: Friend Lee, I have to show files that exist in both folders. If in folder1 exist file START_0109.dat and in folder2 exist rms_20141124_0109.mdb, then the file 109 exist. But I can have several files in both folders. I need a message only if there is a file "*_????.*" in both. If the number "*_????.*" is equal in both folders, then the file exist, else the file doesn't exist. These files can have any number ????, but if both exist, then displaying a message. Sorry for my English! Thank you very much!

Comment: Please edit your question to explain **exactly** what you need, including this new information. Show any code you already have or want to use and tell why it isn't working

Comment: Sjoy, unfortunatelly I don't have code yet. I need something like this: The filename in tokens using the underscore as delimiter in both folders:
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=_"

In first folder is:
D:\Folder1 \ *_????.dat

In second folder is:
D:\Folder2 \ *_????.mdb

If the indicated pattern "*_????.*" match in both folders, then the file exist.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dear Sjoy, I can have several files in folder1, with this pattern "*_????.dat".
D:\Folder1 \
START_0101.dat..
START_0105.dat..
START_0109.dat..
..
..
..
*_????.dat

I can have several files in folder2, with this pattern "*_????.mdb".
D:\Folder2 \
rms_20141124_0100.mdb..
rms_20141124_0108.mdb..
rms_20141124_0109.mdb..
..
..
..
*_????.mdb

I need something like this:

if exist "d:\folder1 \ *_????.*" set "found=1" 
if exist "d:\folder2 \ *_????.*" set "found=2"

if "%1%" EQU "%2%" (
  echo file %found% exist
 ) else (
    echo file doesn't exist
 )

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes. Thanks for editing your question. I am asking: For these files with pattern *_???? that you want to match, is the pattern the numbers  *_0001 through *_1000?

Comment: Mr. Sjoy, Mr. Ricardo gave me a solution I tested here and it worked perfectly. Anyway I thank you all for your support! Thank you very much! This website is wonderful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "folder1=d:\folder1"
    set "folder2=d:\folder2"

    for %%a in ("%folder1%\*.dat") do (
        for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%b in ("%%~na") do (
            if exist "%folder2%\*_%%b.mdb" (
                echo %%b exists
            ) else (
                echo %%b missing
            )
        )
    )
```

For each `.dat` file in folder 1, retrieve a reference to the file in `for` replaceable parameter `%%a`, from it, get the file name (`%%~na`), tokenize it using the underscore as delimiter and retrieve the second token. Show if exist a `.mdb` file in folder 2 with the same token.

**edited** to adapt to multiple subfolders in folder2

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "folder1=d:\folder1"
    set "folder2=d:\folder2"

    for %%a in ("%folder1%\*.dat") do (
        for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%b in ("%%~na") do (

            set "match="
            for /r "%folder2%" %%c in ("*_%%b.mdb") do  if not defined match (
                set "match=1"
                echo %%~nxa located as %%c
            )

            if not defined match (
                echo %%b missing
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Friend "MC ND", I have to show files that exist in both folders. If in folder1 exist file START_0109.dat and in folder2 exist rms_20141124_0109.mdb, then the file 109 exist. But I can have several files in both folders. I need a message only if there is a file "*_????.*" in both. If the number "*_????.*" is equal in both folders, then the file exist, else the file doesn't exist. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'd like to thank Mr. MC ND! I'm really grateful for the quick reply. This code worked just fine! Thank you very much Mr. MC ND!

Comment: Dear MC ND, I need your help again. In d:\folder2\ I have many directories from "d:\folder2\rja", "d:\folder2\rjb" until "d:\folder2\rjz". I have to find out in which directory the file "*_%%b.dat" is located. Example: for /r INICIO_%%b.dat in (%folder3%) do echo file INICIO_%%b.dat is in %folder3%\???

**file INICIO_0104.dat is in d:\folder2\rjj**

Comment: Dear MC ND, I run your code, but the information that I have is:
**INICIO_0111.dat located as C:\folder2\rms_20141124_0111.mdb**
**0205 missing**

I have to figure out which subdirectory in %folder2% the file *_%%b.dat is located too and display this subdirectory.

Like:
**file INICIO_0104.dat is in d:\folder2\rjj**
or
**file INICIO_0104.dat is in rjj**
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AiltonCarvalho, if the text shown is `located as C:\folder2\rms_20141124_0111.mdb`, the file is not inside any subfolder, it is in the `folder2` folder. If you don't want the found file name, change the `echo` line to `echo %%~nxa located in %%~dpc`, that is, the drive and path of the found file

Comment: I just run again with this option, but this script only show me files located in folder d:\folder2. It doesn't show me files located in subfolders. Are there how show me in which subfolder this file exist by script? Like: **file INICIO_0104.dat is in subfolder RJJ**, if the **file INICIO_0104.dat is in d:\folder2\rjj** . Thanks!

Comment: @AiltonCarvalho, does the file exist in this folder? if so, the script is doing its work. If you want to show all the places where the file is found, remove `if not defined match`